# Why can't I drag execution point in IntelliJ (I can in Visual Studio)

Tags: java, .net, visual-studio, debugging, intellij-idea

In Visual Studio, when debugging, one can drag the execution point (current instruction pointer, yellow dot) to another place in the current method.

This is impossible in IntelliJ, and some have stated it's generally impossible in Java. Why?

Comment: Just asked the same question. The related list is working!

Answer (score 16):

IntelliJ interacts with a running JVM through the standard Java debugging interface, so it can debug programs' against different JDKs. This does not support moving the execution point around as you describe.

It does let you wind the call stack back and perform a method call again. In IntelliJ, use the threads window to select a stack frame of a suspended thread and wind back to it. Then continue the thread to re-call the method at that point in the program.

Note: this will not roll back the state of the objects, so strange effects may occur.

Comment: Damn it Visual Studio, why do you have to be so awesome? :P

Comment: I was looking for ways to resume the debug pointer to the start of the method. there's no way as `re-call` the method. for me, I dropped the top frame and re-executed the function.

Comment: I am not finding the threads window. Does it work for Spring Boot applications?

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, if you edit a method being debugged causing the debugged code to be updated the JVM rolls back execution to the first safe place.  Usually this is the first line in that method.

It is very helpful in a debugging scenario.

Answer (score -2):

You can tell the debugger to "Run to line" forward.

Answer (score -8):

Java doesn't have a current execution pointer which can point to a random piece of code. Java assumes the order of execution is in the code, not something you would manipulate.

Perhaps you could explain why you would want to do this and we can let you know another way of achieving the same thing.

Comment: It is very helpful to debugging :)

Comment: An example would be when you have a bug in code which prevents you from executing further, but you're not concerned with it at the moment so you just want to skip that part. Or you want to skip a piece of code to see what would happen if it is not executed (e.g. to prove an assumption correct) and you ant to do it without recompiling the whole thing.

Comment: The whole idea sounds flawed.  You should always be concerned with any bug which prevents execution.  The simplest way to skip over code which you want to ignore is to comment it out, or to evaluate an expression which does what you want.  If you change the contents of one method your IDE should only re-compile that class, not the whole thing.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt, but looks like it only sounds flawed if one never used it. It is an exceptional device to help with the debugging. Not only does it allow one to skip some lines, but it also makes it possible to returns several lines back within the same method and reexecute them. Didn't it occur to you that you had to restart the program, just because you want to reexecute certain lines in the method? The fact that Java does not allow it does not mean it is flawed or unnecessary. It only means that Java developers have less aid when debugging their applications.

Comment: @mark You have a point. My approach is to always debug the simplest example of code which demonstrate the problem. This make restarting and skipping code by commenting it trivial.  However, this is not always possible esp if you have an old code base which was not designed to be modular. In this situation, being able to skip around the code would be a useful alternative. IMHO I would rather be working on clean code which doesn't need it.

Comment: Aren't we all prefer being rich and healthy?

Comment: Moving the execution point is a great tool. C#/VS/.NET does it (and I remember using it back in the day) and it was great. Very useful to test different pieces of code and scenarios. It has nothing to do with "clean modular code".